# Python HTTP Request Capture/Modify

Tags: python, http, fiddler, fiddlercore

I need to replace the SWF file that some web page loads in my browser with a local one, for which i need to capture the http request and edit the route. I can do this manually with Fiddler, but i need to automatize the process.

There exists an API called 'fiddlercore' for .NET framework, i was wondering if anyone knows something like that for python? Or any other way in which this can be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need a program that interacts with your browser  tabs/windows  and if there is a swf object in one of the opened pages, to change it with your local one?

Comment: That's exactly what i need. it would be no problem if i had to embed a browser in the app, whatever as far as i can change the swf file